# Grant connect to user to which is not dba

Tags: oracle, privileges

I want to create user (not DBA) which have grant to create user, drop user, alter user and can grant connect, resource to other users he has created.

So I've create one user e.g. user ABC as follows

```
create user abc identified by abc;
grant connect, resource, create user, drop user, alter user to abc;
```

Now user abc can create other user but it has no grant to give grant of connect and resource to the users it has created.

How can I allow abc so he can grant connect, resource to the users it has created.

Comment: What specific database are you using? MySQL?

Comment: I'm using oracle 11g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grant connect, resource, create user, drop user, alter user to abc 
WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```